# sql query not working for stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in sql server.When I try to use the php function to get the results,its not working.

```
echo mssql_query(exec MOB_uspcommunication_details $userID,'send');
```

This gives result as `1` instead of resourceID.When I run the query in sql server its giving me the result.
When I change the second parameter to some other value like this,its working from PHP side.

```
 echo mssql_query(exec MOB_uspcommunication_details $userID,'inbox');
```

This gives me resourceid#10 and I am getting the results.

For the first query,I am not able to understand why this happens.Please help me

Comment: Could add little more context (e.g. code) to be able to solve your problem? That's a little bit to broad

Answer (score 0):

From [the PHP documentation:](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php)

### Return Values

---

> Returns a MS SQL result resource on success, TRUE if no rows were returned, or FALSE on error.

So that means that the first function call returns `1` to indicate there were no rows (1 == true in PHP). The second function call actually retrieves the rows from your table.

Comment: I don't think that this addresses the problem of the question. It's furthermore a problem with executing the stored procedure on the php server. Because the user states that the stored procedure works on the server itself.

Comment: When I try to run the first query in sql server,its giving me the results

Comment: @rbr94 Sorry about that; I misunderstood the question. In that case, what version of PHP is being used? This function is deprecated in PHP7.